# How to get VSCode's terminal to recognize python

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm just getting started with learning python and this is my first project. I'm trying to write a bot for a simple game and I'm trying to run a command in the terminal at the bottom of vs code to check if pyautogui is installed correctly in my workspace. I can do "pip list" from my computers terminal and I see pyautogui from the list but vscode terminal window says

```
The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct, and try again.
```

At line:1 char:1

- pip list
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Have you got the python extension installed in VSCode?

Comment: Yes i do, its just the terminal in vscode thats saying pip isnt a recognized command. the syntax is working fine.

Comment: What's your OS, like in windows there're cmd and powershell, are you using the same one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me a few times before and I believe that it is a path issue in Windows. So, the easiest way to fix this is to let Anaconda do it for you.

Go this link: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#windows

Then, click on the download button. Once it is downloaded, the installer will ask if you would like to let Anaconda modify your path, say yes. Let anaconda make the alterations that it needs.

Then, restart your visual studios code and try pip again.

Comment: I don't think your link points to the intended website

Comment: Good catch, thank you. I updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

VScode uses a virtual environment, so you have to install the modules from VScode.

try to use pip3 instead of pip (if you use python3.x).
otherwise try to install pip with 'python get -pip.py'.

Comment: ok so python 3.9 is installed on my computer straight from there website, so vscode wont see that ? i ran that in terminal in vscode and this is what it said "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases." but python is installed straight from the store and it says uninstall or disable.

Comment: also i type in py in terminal in vscode it says python 3.9.1 is installed

Comment: the first sentence of this answer is incorrect